# Infinite loop while opening new activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a problem with the following code while working on android project in Eclipse:

```
/
.
.
.
    myTimer = new Timer();
            myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {          
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TimerMethod();
                }

            }, 0, 1000);
/
.
.
.           
    private void TimerMethod()
        {
            this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
        }

        private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Time_Between();

            }
        };

    public void Time_Between (){


            time_end = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if ( ( time_end - time_start )/ 1000 > 30) 
            {

            startActivity(i);
            finish();

            }
    }
```

What I'd like it to do is to check whether elapsed time is >30 and if so it should open another activity (i), and kill the current one. However after 30 seconds it opens activity "i" multiple times instead only once, just like an  infinite loop. Looks like the old one activity is still running in the background? I don't really know the reason. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: after 30 seconds elapsed, start activity i, and kill the current one

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( ( time_end - time_start )/ 1000 > 30)
```

Once this hits > 30 theres nothing to stop it from still being > 30. Your timer is still running and thus every time it ticks it's checking against that IF statement and executing accordingly.

If you want this to happen only once throughout the lifetime of the timer, stop the timer before you start the new activity.

If you want this to happen continuously every 30, restart your timer before starting the new activity.

Answer (score 0):

`Handler.postDelayed` is a more efficient way of doing post checking.

try this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
}, 30 * 1000);
```

Comment: well just so you know, this is better, it's the android OS that handles it, without you checking on it every time